# Return type strengthening depending on whether optional param is passed

Tags: typescript

Suppose we need to implement a method which returns something, but when this something is `undefined`, it should return some default value passed in instead. But we don't want to make the default value param required, so are declaring it as an optional one:

```
private returnSomething(someParam: string, defaultValue?: string) : string | undefined {
    const result: string | undefined = ...; // Some result-producing logic
    return result !== undefined ? result : defaultValue;
}
```

And we expect the following to compile in strict mode (notice `something1: string` type which is declared without the `undefined` part):

```
const something1: string = this.returnSomething("someParam1", "?"); // Error, no undefined in the type of something1
const something2: string | undefined = this.returnSomething("someParam2");
```

Is it possible to declare a method in TypeScript so that when an optional parameter is not passed the return type of the method is considered as `string | undefined` whereas when it's passed, the return type becomes `string`?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev: Thank you! Fixed. It was copy-paste issue :)

Answer (score 2):

So if I got you correctly, this is easy with a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type:

```
const returnSomething = <D extends string | undefined>(someParam: string, defaultValue?: D) : D extends undefined ? string | undefined : string => {

  const result = {} as any;

  return result !== undefined ? result : defaultValue;
}
```

See the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20returnSomething%20%3D%20%3CD%20extends%20string%20%7C%20undefined%3E(someParam%3A%20string%2C%20defaultValue%3F%3A%20D)%20%3A%20D%20extends%20undefined%20%3F%20string%20%7C%20undefined%20%3A%20string%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20any%3B%0A%0A%20%20return%20result%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%20%3F%20result%20%3A%20defaultValue%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20something1%3A%20string%20%3D%20returnSomething(%22someParam1%22%2C%20%22%3F%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20No%20error%0Aconst%20something2%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%20%20%3D%20returnSomething(%22someParam2%22)%3B)

UPD to avoid error when using without `any` :

```
const returnSomething = <D extends string | undefined, R extends D extends undefined ? string | undefined : string>(someParam: string, defaultValue?: D) : R => {

  const result = 'str';

  return (result !== undefined ? result : defaultValue) as R;
}
```

UPD2. The correct approach (and my apologies for messing this up).

I want to give my apologies because I've introduced generics and conditional types, when they were unnecessary. I mean, I didn't know they can cause such an error. But I also was misguided by the original question.
So the normal way, how I would make it, looks like this:

```
const returnSomething = (someParam: string, defaultValue?: string): string | undefined => {

    const result = '';

    return result !== undefined ? result : defaultValue;
}

const something1 = returnSomething("someParam1", "?");
const something2 = returnSomething("someParam2");
```

That's it. And yes, you should not assign types to `something1` and `something2`. Instead, you should runtime-check (and typescript infers types from the checking):

```
if (typeof something1 === 'undefined') { 
    /* oops the value is undefined, do something to make the program continue working properly */ 
} 
else {
    something1 // has type "string"
}
```

Regarding the error, I've submitted an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28917).

Comment: Thank you! It removed error for the `something1: string` case, but now we're able to declare `something2: string` without the `undefined` part and no compiler error gets produced (can't give the whole Playground link since it's too long for a comment, but the relevant part is: `const something2: string = returnSomething("someParam2"); // For some reason, no error`). Do you know how to cover this case as well?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov Sorry, I can't understand what's wrong, can you elaborate? What error should be produced in the second case? You know, `string` is a subset of `string | undefined`. Can you explain pls..

Comment: Sure. When we call `const something2: string = returnSomething("someParam2");`, `defaultValue` is basically `undefined`. So, `undefined` could potentially be returned from `returnSomething()`. But compiler allows us to declare `const something2: string = ...` which is incorrect, since we know that it's `const something2: string | undefined = ...`. Does it make sense?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov user y2bd has given the correct answer, I had a silly mistake in my code. Fixed now.

Comment: Well, I guess this tiny glitch is completely understandable :) I think TS compiler should warn us that we're doing something pointless in this case. Hopefully, they'll implement this warning some day.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately UPD2 you've added completely undermine the goal of this question. If we declare the return type of the `returnSomething()` method as `string | undefined`, a compiler would not protect us from an `undefined` returned from the method. so we have to always guard the code with `if (something2 !== undefined) { console.log(something2.length); }` or a similar run-time check instead of a compile-time check done by the compiler automatically.

Comment: As for UPD, I'm still getting a compiler error: `Type 'string | D | undefined' is not assignable to type 'R'`.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov See the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28917) especially [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28917#issuecomment-445966413) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26933)

Answer (score 1):

Nurbol was most of the way there, I had to make one additional change to get it fully working:

```
const returnSomething = <D extends string | undefined>(someParam: string, defaultValue?: D) : D extends undefined ? string | undefined : string => {
  const result = {} as any;
  return result !== undefined ? result : defaultValue;
}

const something1: string = returnSomething("someParam1", "d"); // No error
const something2: string | undefined = returnSomething("someParam2"); // No error
const something3: string = returnSomething("someParam2"); // Yes error
const something4: string = returnSomething("someParam2", undefined); // Yes error
```

We need to define `D` to accept `undefined` initially, otherwise the conditional will always return just `string`.

The side effect of this though is that you are now allowed to pass `undefined` as a default value. It still errors as expected though.

You could also do this with function overloads:

```
function returnSomething(param: string): string | undefined;
function returnSomething(param: string, defaultValue: string): string;
function returnSomething(param: string, defaultValue?: string) {
  const result = {} as any;
  return result !== undefined ? result: defaultValue;
}
```

This avoids the `undefined` issue.

Comment: Yeah, correct. Great explanation, BTW! OMG I was silly. I gave the `D` type `string` and in the condition was trying to check if it's `string | undefined` lol.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, guys! I've tried to use it, but ran into an issue when changed `const result = {} as any;` line to a real-world case `const result = "";`. The compiler error is: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'D extends undefined ? string : string'`. @NurbolAlpysbayev, you might be interesting in looking into this as well.

Comment: In the function-overload method you haven't declared a specific return type for `returnSomething()`. This prevents the compiler from compile-time type checking and, subsequently, to the run-time errors. Example: `const something2: string | undefined = this.returnSomething("someParam2"); console.log(something2.length);` compiles ok, but will fail at run-time if `undefined` would be returned from the `returnSomething()` method.